# After exiting from function, nodes aren't saved

Tags: c++, nodes

My program should create a linked list and show it. My problem is when the addelemnt_end function ends, it doesn't update `head` and `last`.
I tried with debug and when my function is done, the info and next part from head and last are "unable to read memory".

```
struct node{
int info;
node *next;
};

node *head, *last;

void addelement_end(node *head, node *last, int element)
{if (head == NULL)
    {   node *temp = new node;
        temp->info = element;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last = temp;
        head = temp;

    }
    else {node*temp = new node;
        last->next = temp;
        temp->info = element;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last = temp;
    }
}
void show(node* head, node *last)
{


if (head==NULL)
        cout << "Empty list";

    else
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->info << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int x, n, i;
cout << "how many numbers";
    cin >> n;

head = last = NULL;
for (i =1; i <= n; i++)
{
    cin >> x;
    addelement_end(head, last, x);

}
show(head, last);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very common error. Here is a similar illustration of the problem:

```
int change_a(int a) {
    a = 42;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    change_a(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print 10 because in the function `change_a` you are only modifying a copy of the value contained in the variable `a`.

The correct solution is passing a pointer (or using a reference since you are using C++).

```
int change_a(int *a) {
    *a = 42;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    change_a(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

But maybe you're going to tell me: "I'm already using a pointer!". Yes, but a pointer is just a variable. If you want to change where the pointer points, you need to pass a pointer to that pointer.

So, try this:

```
void addelement_end(node **head, node **last, int element)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {   node *temp = new node;
        temp->info = element;
        temp->next = NULL;
        *last = temp;
        *head = temp;
    }
    else {
        node *temp = new node;
        (*last)->next = temp;
        temp->info = element;
        temp->next = NULL;
        *last = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how should i call the function? I've tried many possibilities and every time i get this error C2664: 'void addelement_end(node **,node **,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'node *' to 'node **'

Comment: @user3125464 by giving the address of the variables:  `addelement_end(&head, &last, x);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, it works. If you know good materials to learn pointers will be great.